Why does the Python datetime.replace() method return a new object instead of mutate the existing object?
Calling the .replace() method on a Python DateTime object returns a new instance of a DateTime object instead of mutating the existing object. This seems to be a common pitfall when learning the method.

The documentation does say that's what it does.

@ndc85430 that's correct. I was curious why DateTime objects appear to be immutable. It seems like immutability is useful feature for primitives (int, str, etc.) but does not seem to make sense for a more complex objects.

On the contrary, a whole style of programming has developed around making data immutable where possible (along with other ideas). The answer to your question alludes to some of the reasons why (avoiding certain problems when you're dealing with multiple threads). However, it's about more than just that - it can help to make it easier to reason about your programs. I like this talk by Kevlin Henney on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APUCMSPiNh4.

datetime objects in Python are immutable - this is an intentional design choice that provides thread safety and predictable behavior. This immutable behavior is consistent with other built-in Python types like strings and tuples. It's a powerful feature that helps prevent unintended side effects in your code.
So this is a sample usage:
from datetime import datetime

# Create a datetime object
current_date = datetime(2024, 12, 12, 12, 30)

# Correct usage - assign the new value
new_date = current_date.replace(hour=15)

# Now new_date has hour=15, while current_date remains unchanged
print(new_date)        # 2024-12-12 15:30:00
print(current_date)    # 2024-12-12 12:30:00

